# Postgres NULLIF greater than x

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a query to aggregate some data and in my select statement I want to write this:

`select coalesce(nullif(sum(field)), '> 1'), 1) from ...`

Which, if NULLIF was capable of it, would give me the sum of `field` unless it was greater than 1, in which case it would give me 1. Of course, I'm asking the impossible of NULLIF, which is intended to do a basic string comparison only.

The reason I don't want to use a CASE statement is because where I have substituted `field` is an enormous expression which I would have to write out twice if I were to do:

`select case when sum(field) > 1 then 1 else sum(field) from ...`

I was hoping postgres has an ace up its sleeve and I wouldn't have to do that. Anyone come across this dilemma before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want the minimum of the sum and 1? That't the `LEAST` function:

```
select LEAST(sum(field), 1) from ...
```